# Display Facebook page content according to country domain

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Can Facebook page content be displayed according to country domain? For example, I have a Facebook page but entering by different country domain, Facebook will display that country's content only.

Comment: What is “that country's content”? Are you talking about _targeting_ options?

Comment: @CBroe, country's content like if I have a particular event for India, it will only display in India, post for HK it will only display in HK. Im actually new to FB, so i don't know what is _targeting_ option.

Comment: Well then how do you do that, post “for” India or HK?

Comment: @CBroe I haven't done it yet. I was thinking if it is possible and how to do it.

Comment: Then you should probably consult Facebook’s Help section first; so far this does not sound like a programing question.